# Add data to array in loop

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I have an "do - while" loop with 5000 numbers that should get added to an array during each run through the loop like this:

The problem is that every time the loop is executed, the numbers get overwritten and only the last runthrough of data is in the array once the loop finishes.

I use this code:

```
    long cursor = -1;
    long[] fArray = new long[100000];  // more than enough space in array
    IDs ids = twitter.getFollowersIDs(name, cursor); // start with first page of 5000 numbers

    do 
    {                       
        ids = twitter.getFollowersIDs(name, cursor);            
        fArray = twitter.getFollowersIDs(name, cursor).getIDs(); // this gets Array with 5000 numbers every time until "empty"
        cursor = ids.getNextCursor();   // jump to next array with 5000 new numbers     
    } while (ids.hasNext());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always only writing into the first 5000 elements of your very huge array.

Instead you want to assign the result of the getFollowersIDs() call to a separate *local* array and afterwards use [arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to copy the 5000 current followers into the much larger array of all followers.

Comment: Could the downvoter please add a comment indicating what's wrong with this answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

at line `fArray = twitter.getFollowersIDs(name, cursor).getIDs(); // this gets Array with 5000 numbers every time until "empty"`
 you are doing simple assignment to your array `fArray`.

you should use something like this

```
long tempArr[] = twitter.getFollowersIDs(name, cursor).getIDs();

for (int i = previous_length_of_array; i < previous_length_of_array + tempArray.length; i++)
   fArray[i] = tempArr[1 - previous_length_of_array];
```

P.S:
The above code isn't tested nor compiled, just tried to give you example what you should do

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to declare fArray to be 2-dimensional.
Sample brief code:
long fArray[][];

int index = 0;

[Begin inside a loop]
some code...

fArray[index] = twitter.getFollowersIDs(name, cursor).getIDs();
index++;

some code...
[End inside a loop]

I hope that's clear and simple.